# Tag Merge Request: [sortable] and [jquery-ui-sortable]

Tags: support, retag-request

Based on the description [sortable](/questions/tagged/sortable) is jQuery-UI's sortable.  There is another, more descriptive tag [jquery-ui-sortable](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui-sortable).  I would suggest that sortable is removed and merged into jquery-ui-sortable.

Comment: Yes, merged and *not* made synonyms.

Comment: Good point, let me remove the synonym tag.

Comment: Also should merge jquery-sortable.

Comment: @JustinSatyr - Why not synonyms?

Comment: @gilly3 I now meet the requirements to suggest a synonym.  I'll suggest `jquery-sortable` and see how that goes